# A simpler way to code this onclick background change - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, timeline

Is there a way to simplify this code? I just find it too long for a simple function.

I tried to use querySelectorAll(), but I had a hard time trying to re-code it.

Please see snippet included.

I tried to look for a simplier way, unfortunately I am unable to find any.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
if (moreText.style.display === "none") {
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("more2").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
  document.getElementById("myBtn2").style.backgroundColor = "#006668";
} else {
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("more2").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
  document.getElementById("myBtn2").style.backgroundColor = "#006668";
  } } 
  function myFunction2() {
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more2");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
if (moreText.style.display === "none") {
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("more").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.backgroundColor = "#006668";
  document.getElementById("myBtn2").style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
} else {
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("more").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.backgroundColor = "#006668";
  document.getElementById("myBtn2").style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
  } } 
   function myFunction3() {
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more3");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn3");
if (moreText.style.display === "none") {
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("more").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("more2").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.backgroundColor = "#006668";
  document.getElementById("myBtn2").style.backgroundColor = "#006668";
} else {
   moreText.style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("more").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("more2").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.backgroundColor = "#006668";
  document.getElementById("myBtn2").style.backgroundColor = "#006668";
  } }
```

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #006668;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#more {display: none;}
#more2 {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn" href="#Event1">Event 1</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction2()" id="myBtn2" href="#Event2">Event 2</a>
  </div>
  <span id="more">Display Event Here 1.</span>
<span id="more2">Display Event Here 2.</span>
```

[It's supposed to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pIfX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```js
const myBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".myBtn");
const descriptions = document.querySelectorAll(".description");

function myFunction(e) {
 myBtns.forEach( btn => {  
  btn.classList.remove("active");
 });
 
 descriptions.forEach( description => {
  description.classList.remove("show");    
 });
 e.target.classList.add("active");
 document.querySelector("."+e.target.getAttribute("data-show")).classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: orange;
}
.hide {
 display: none;
}

.show {
 display: block;
}

.active {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
 <a onclick="myFunction(event)" class="myBtn" href="#Event1" data-show="more">Event 1</a>
 <a onclick="myFunction(event)" class="myBtn" href="#Event2" data-show="more2">Event 2</a>
</div>
 <span class="hide description more">Display Event Here 1.</span>
 <span class="hide description more2">Display Event Here 2.</span>
```

Comment: Hi sir, I think this does it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

See my comments in the updated example below.

On click we remove ALL the active classes on the buttons and on the text areas and than add the active class to the ones that need it.

The advantage here is that you are not storing the active class in javascript. 
This way you do not risk the chance to have representation and stored state to get out of sync by other scripts that might be running..

```js
// first we get all the buttons and text areas
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
var mores = document.querySelectorAll('.more');

// we add an event listener by looping trough all the buttons
for (const btn of btns) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}

// handle the button click
function handleClick(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // remove the active class on ALL the buttons
  for (const btn of btns) {
    btn.classList.remove('active');
  }
  // add the active class on the clicked button
  event.target.classList.add('active');
  
  //remove the active class on all the text areas
  for (const more of mores) {
    more.classList.remove('active');
  }
  // here we get the data-show attribute of the clicked element 
  // and use it to show the right text area
  document.querySelector(`#${event.target.dataset.show}`).classList.add('active'); 
}
```

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #006668;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn.active{
  background: #000000;
}

.more{
  display: none;
}

.more.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a class="btn" href="#" data-show="more1" >Event 1</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#" data-show="more2">Event 2</a>
</div>
<span id="more1" class="more">Display Event Here 1.</span>
<span id="more2" class="more">Display Event Here 2.</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I now know where I missed, I tried to recode it like this, document.querySelectorAll("btn","btn1","btn2".....) because I was trying to exclude a single ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using below `javascript` you can make it simpler way

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  var href = event.target.href.substring(event.target.href.indexOf('#') + 1);
  var id = event.target.id;
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  var y = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  var i,j;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
    y[j].style.backgroundColor = "#006668";
  }
  document.getElementById(href).style.display = 'inline';
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
}
```

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #006668;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn" href="#Event1">Event 1</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn2" href="#Event2">Event 2</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn3" href="#Event3">Event 3</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn4" href="#Event4">Event 4</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn5" href="#Event5">Event 5</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn6" href="#Event6">Event 6</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn7" href="#Event7">Event 7</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn8" href="#Event8">Event 8</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn9" href="#Event9">Event 9</a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)" id="myBtn10" href="#Event10">Event 10</a>
</div>
<span id="Event1">Display Event Here 1.</span>
<span id="Event2">Display Event Here 2.</span>
<span id="Event3">Display Event Here 3.</span>
<span id="Event4">Display Event Here 4.</span>
<span id="Event5">Display Event Here 5.</span>
<span id="Event6">Display Event Here 6.</span>
<span id="Event7">Display Event Here 7.</span>
<span id="Event8">Display Event Here 8.</span>
<span id="Event9">Display Event Here 9.</span>
<span id="Event10">Display Event Here 10.</span>
```

Comment: Hi sir, can you please elaborate this line to me? document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "#000000"; I'm worried that this might affect other id's within the page, correct me if I'm wrong, sir.

Comment: @pjustindaryll no it will not affect, we have taken variable var id = event.target.id; instead of it you can change variable name yourself anything

Answer (score -2):

```css
.px-0 {
      padding-left: 0 !important;
      padding-right: 0 !important;
    }
    ul.nav.nav-tabs {
     background-color: #006668;
    }
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li a,ul.nav.nav-tabs li a:hover {
     color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active a,ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active a:hover {
     background-color: #000;   
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .tab-content {
     padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
  

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Event 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Event 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Event 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Event 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <p>Display Event Here 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <p>Display Event Here 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <p>Display Event Here 3.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <p>Display Event Here 4.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure the question includes showing/hiding the content.

Including the whole bootstrap css library, the full jquery library and bootstrap JS (total over 60KB) might be a bit overkill for what we're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I was actually planning to include this animation after i simplified the code, thank you for including it.